# Query to display playlist songs returns empty?

Tags: android, listview, mediastore

I'm trying to figure out a `MediaStore` query that will fetch all the member songs of a `Playlist`. However, the `List` always returns empty with no results (even after notifying the adapter). Here's what im currently doing...

**Get Playlist Songs Method**

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistID);
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM);
        int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum, thisPath));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    musicCursor.close();
```

And here's how i add the values into the Playlist using it's ID...

**Add Playlist Songs Method**

```
public static void addToPlaylist(ContentResolver resolver, long audioId, String title, String artist, String album, String path) {

    String[] cols = new String[] {
            "count(*)"
    };
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistID);
    Cursor cur = resolver.query(uri, cols, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    cur.close();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audioId);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST, artist);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM, album);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA, path);
    resolver.insert(uri, values);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a while bit I was on holiday.
To add to a playlist, you simply need the audio_id and the play_order and the playlist_id of course. The code below has cursor and a where clause as this allows you to add more than one track but it is not needed if you have the audio_id already

```
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri exturi = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
            "external", playlist_id);
    where = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";
    String[] whereVal = {music_id};

    Uri mediauri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = resolver.query(mediauri, projection, where, whereVal,
            null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String audio_id = c.getString(idColumn);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, base);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audio_id);
            resolver.insert(exturi, values);
            base++;
        }
        c.close();
    }
```

To get all tracks on a playlist, I have the following code:

```
         public Cursor getPlaylistTracks(Context context, Long playlist_id) {
    Uri newuri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
            "external", playlist_id);
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID;
    String audio_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID;
    String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST;
    String album = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM;
    String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM_ID;
    String title = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE;
    String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DURATION;
    String location = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA;
    String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.COMPOSER;
    String playorder = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER;

    String date_modified = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATE_MODIFIED;
    String[] columns = {_id, audio_id, artist, album_id, album, title, duration,
            location, date_modified, playorder, composer};
    return resolver.query(newuri, columns, null, null, null);

}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I do not understand why someone down voted this without explaining